# R: changing some column values, but not all, based on other column's values: problems with ifelse() and if(){}

Tags: r, if-statement

I want to change certain values in one column (B) if a certain value appears in another column (A) but otherwise for the column values to remain unchanged. For example, in the following simplified version of my data I want to change the value in column B to be "0" if the value in column A is "none" otherwise I want the values in column B to remain unchanged

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1:4),A=c("1/wk","none","1/mo","1/wk"),B=c("3",NA,NA,"depends"))
    > df
      ID    A       B
    1  1 1/wk       3
    2  2 none    <NA>
    3  3 1/mo    <NA>
    4  4 1/wk depends
```

I tried this

```
df$B <- ifelse(df$A == "none","0",df$B)
    > df
      ID    A    B
    1  1 1/wk    1
    2  2 none    0
    3  3 1/mo <NA>
    4  4 1/wk    2
```

While this does change ID 2 to "0" in column B (which I want), it also changes the other values in column B. I want my output to look like this:

```
> df
  ID    A       B
1  1 1/wk       3
2  2 none       0
3  3 1/mo    <NA>
4  4 1/wk depends
```

I also tried to use if(){} but can't figure out how to use it when there are multiple columns involved

I am not particular about what function to use (though I prefer answers that use base R). PS - while I have found similar questions on stackoverflow none of the answers have worked for me.

Comment: You're seeing issues because `df$B` starts out as a factor - it might be better to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating `df` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. That data frame was just an example - I extracted my data from a csv file. However, now that I know that the data's structure was the problem I changed df$B into a numerical structure and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating your data frame without using factors:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1:4),
                 A=c("1/wk","none","1/mo","1/wk"),
                 B=c("3",NA,NA,"depends"),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)      # add this
df$B <- ifelse(df$A == "none","0",df$B)
df

  ID    A       B
1  1 1/wk       3
2  2 none       0
3  3 1/mo    <NA>
4  4 1/wk depends
```

The problem with the comparison is that you are doing it against *factor* levels, not the values they represent.

Here is what is happening with your current comparison:

```
df$A [
    "1/wk" != "none"  => "1" (first factor level of df$B)
    "none" == "none"  => "0" (the comparison having been true)
    "1/mo" != "none"  => NA  (comparison failed, NA still NA for factors)
    "1/wk" != "none"  => "2" (second factor level of df$B)
]
```

Comment: That would be fine but in my real data, column "B" is a factor (thats what R decided it was from the csv file). I want that column to be numerical in the end but if I change it to numerical before I've corrected those NA values to 0s it just makes all those rows NA - Im doing df$B <- as.numeric(as.character(df$B)

Comment: Your `B` column certainly appears to start out with text, not just numbers.  There is no major reason why you can't just work with characters instead of factors.

Comment: Thanks. Before when I was running df$B <- as.numeric(as.character(df$B) it was making the whole row NA but now its not for some reason. So I just made B have a numerical structure and then ran the ifelse function and its giving me what I want (I wanted the depends to become NA anyway). Thanks for giving such a clear explanation as to why it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

the Problem is that by default your columns are not character vectors but factors.

Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1:4),A=c("1/wk","none","1/mo","1/wk"),B=c("3",NA,NA,"depends"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```